Definition of derivative between normed spaces
In our class, we learned that a function $f$ from a normed space $\mathcal{X}$ to a normed space $\mathcal{Y}$ is differentiable at $x\in\mathcal{X}$ if there exists a bounded linear transformation $A$ from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{Y}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah\|_\mathcal{Y}}{\|h\|_\mathcal{X}}=0 
\end{equation}
The fact that the derivative $A$ must be bounded makes sense to me since we later use the fact $A$ can be assigned an operator norm to prove Chain Rule for function between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$. Yet, I wonder if there exists a function $f$ from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{Y}$ and a corresponding unbounded linear transformation $B:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ that satisfy the same equation?
I can't come up with an example myself since I do Calculus mostly only in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and we all know linear transformation between finite-dimensional vector space must be bounded.

Edit: As @geetha290krm pointed out, any unbounded linear transformation $f$ should do, but I wish there can be a less trivial example.

Differentiation on polynomials should work?

@julio_es_sui_glace Please elaborate. Thanks for your help in advance.

My comment is only an example of a linear unbounded operator, so the answer below subsumes my comment

Take any unbounded linear map $A$ from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{Y}$ and take $f=A$. Then, $\frac{\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah\|_\mathcal{Y}}{\|h\|_\mathcal{X}}=0$ for every $h$. [Of course, in finite dimensions, all linear maps are bounded].

Thank you for your input. It helps me a lot, but if this requirement isn't too much, I wish someone can give me a less trivial example.
